coloring a 5*5 grid with minimum number of colors
In my math homework assignment my teacher gave us the following problem:
Determine the minimum number of colors required to paint the squares of a 5 × 5 square
grid in such a way that every three consecutive squares in any direction (vertical, horizontal or diagonal) are three different colors. Be sure to justify why the squares cannot be colored using a smaller number of colors.
I simplified the idea by considering a 3 x 3 grid and found the minimum number of colors that can fill the grid without any colors in any direction being  identical and managed to find a total of 6 colors by inspecting various examples. I got stuck at this point and I am unable to continue.

For the 3x3 case, can't you just do: 123,213,432 for 4 colours.

When is the homework due?

@MathieuRundström, your solution has two identical colors in the main diagonal $(112)$ and in the third column $(332)$.

For $3 \times 3$, $5$ colors is possible: $142\531\425$.

@MyMolecules tommorow

Were you able to make progress? With hints given in answer by Chris and comments, 4 colours are not sufficient but 5 colours seem to be.

I'll use notation like "B4" to mean the cell in the second row and fourth column.
Hint 1: start from C3. Call its colour $1$. Now you know several cells must have a colour different to $1$; for example, cell A3. Say its colour is $2$.
Now as well as cells whose colour can't be $1$, you have some whose colour can be neither $1$ nor $2$; like C1. Call its colour $3$.
Next look at A1; finally at B2. What does this tell you about the minimum number of colours you need?
Hint 2: once you've shown it can't be done with fewer than $n$ colours, show that it can be done with $n$ colours. It's a little tricky, but if you carry on the process in hint 1 it comes together quite quickly.
Hint 3: don't forget that the condition only applies to rows, columns and diagonals of length $3$. This means A2 and B1 could be the same colour.

I am still unable to solve it can you give further guidance

How far did you get with the hints?

after further trial  i was able to solve it thank you very mmuch
